# Youtube Player API Throws 404

Tags: javascript, html, api, youtube, http-status-code-404

This has been bugging me for a while now, I am using this generic script to create a player

`var player = new YT.Player(videoArray[0], { videoId : videoArray[0], events : { 'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange } });`

I have the callback function set up with just a simple console.log the problem is when I change the state of a player the console throws

https://www.youtube.com/get_video?noflv=1&video_id=ghUA.... GET 404 from the file html5player-en_US-vfloyxzv5.js:39 witch I asume is loaded by the YouTube Iframe API.

Any ideeas or posibile solutions will be greatly apreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong, I am posting this maybe it will help someone along the way.

Since the videoArray was holding jQuery object, I used this piece of code to get it all working.

```
    if(isYouTubeVideo) {
        videoID = iframeSrc.substr(baseUrlLength);
    }

    videoArray[i] = {};
    videoArray[i].id = videoID;

    jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + videoID + '?v=2&alt=json'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        videoArray[i].title = data.entry.title.$t;
    });

    jQuery(this).attr('id', videoID);
    playerArray[i] = new YT.Player(videoArray[i].id, { event : //Events here})
```

I hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, this is one of the numerous little things you'll have to cope with using the Youtube Player API. **I don't think there is any solution**, and we can only wait for a Youtube fix.

A bug report has already been created, feel free to [vote for it](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6267).

Youtube player is **updated every tuesday**. Hopefully, this will be fixed **someday**.

Answer (score 0):

I get this for certain videos.  In my experience, **the get_video 404 doesn't matter** - the video still loads correctly.

There is one random caveat though; if you're running this on an iPhone connected to Mac Safari Web Inspector, the 404 causes the video to stop loading.  This caused me hours of fun!